# Power series such that the $n$-th partial sum has $n$ distinct roots

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, power-series

I am looking for examples of power series of the form

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k$$

(where $a_k \in \mathbb{C}$ for all $k$) such that the polynomial given by its $n$-th partial sum has $n$ *distinct* roots, i.e.:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k$$

has $n$ distinct roots.

So far, I have found this family of examples: $\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k$ and all of its derivatives. Can you help me find some examples that are not any of these?

Comment: Note that a polynomial $P$ has a repeated root $z_0$ if and only if $P(z_0)=P'(z_0)=0$ so, for example, $e^z$ works since $P'_n=P_n-\frac{z^n}{n!}$ so the only common zero possible for $P_n, P'_n$ would be $0$ and that is plainly not the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that
the exponential function
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^n}{n!}
$
does this.

Here is one paper
discussion the roots
of the partial sums,
although I don't see a proof
that all the roots are distinct.

https://sites.math.washington.edu/~morrow/336_09/papers/Ian.pdf

After further search,
I found this,
which does prove
that all the zeros are simple:

https://maa.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00029890.2005.11920265

It is the American Mathematical Monthly,
2005, vol. 10, p. 891.

Comment: that is trivial as noted in my comment under the question ($P'_n=P_n-\frac{z^n}{n!}$ so the only double zero could be $0$ and that is not the case)

Comment: These papers actually helped me a lot with my research. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

Let $a_k$ be a sequence of numbers that are algebraically independent over the rationals.  Thus for any nontrivial polynomial $p(x_0, \ldots, x_n)$ with rational coefficients, $p(a_0, \ldots, a_n) \ne 0$.

The polynomial $P_n(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + \ldots + a_n x^n$ has a repeated root if and only if its discriminant is $0$.  In this case that discriminant is a nontrivial polynomial in $a_0, \ldots, a_n$ with integer coefficients, and therefore must be nonzero.

Comment: As far as I understand, if $f(z) = a_nz^n+\ldots+a_2z^2+a_1z+a_0$ the discriminant is $D(f) = (-1)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}\frac{1}{a_n}Res(f,f^\prime)$. Is it still a polynomial in $a_0,\ldots,a_n$ even after dividing by $a_n$?